# Firebase on React Native - dependencies issue

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging functionnalities on React Native (I would like to use notifications).

However I'm stucked on an error, related to the dependencies.

When running `react-native run-android` I get the following error

```
D:\wrkfldr\Hiking\android\app\src\main\java\com\hiking\MainApplication.java:6: error: package io.invertase.firebase does not exist
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
                            ^
D:\wrkfldr\Hiking\android\app\src\main\java\com\hiking\MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            new RNFirebasePackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class RNFirebasePackage
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
```

Here are the dependencies in my app\build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0"
    compile project(':react-native-cardview')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Here is the MainApplication.java

```
package com.hiking;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import com.kishanjvaghela.cardview.RNCardViewPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRMessagingPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new RNFirebasePackage(),
            new FIRMessagingPackage(),
            new RNCardViewPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  ...
}
```

I really can't figure out where the issue is. Has someone any idea ?

Comment: what library are you using? `react-native-firebase`?

Comment: Yes. After checking package.json I have `"react-native-firebase": "^3.2.7"` and `"react-native-fcm": "^13.3.1"`

Comment: You don't need `react-native-fcm`, `react-native-firebase` already got support for Cloud Messaging :-P, you can get rid of `react-native-fcm` and follow the instructions here https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/installation/android / https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/messaging/android

Comment: Even if I would like to use push notifications ? I've been looking at [evollu](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) which requires `react-native-fcm`. Is there another way to implement push notifications ?

Comment: Well, if you only want push notifications and you don't need any other things from firebase, you could get rid of `react-native-firebase` and go with `react-native-fcm` (you'll have to remove `import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;` and `new RNFirebasePackage()` from your `MainApplication.java`)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to use evollu as standalone. The documentation was a bit confused to me

Answer (score 0):

try to import and use RNFirebaseMessagingPackage instead FIRMessagingPackage

```
...
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
...
new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
...
```

also make sure that you have react-native-fcm in packege.json file, if not make

```
npm i react-native-fcm --save
```